# Citeproc-org error after updating to debian buster - void function libxml-parse-xml-region

Tags: xml, debugging, emacs, org-mode, citations

I am able to insert article citations in org mode using org-cite-insert but when i try to export it to html i get the following error. It worked beautifully a day ago but is acting up after i basically powerwashed my chromebook to install debian buster. Would really appreciate any advice.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function libxml-parse-xml-region)
  libxml-parse-xml-region(1 11035)
  citeproc-style-parse("/home/arcotpixel/Zotero/styles/american-medical-as...")
  citeproc-create-style("/home/pixel/Zotero/styles/american-medical-as..." #f(compiled-function (loc) #<bytecode -0x18864415d32d6563>) "en" nil)
  citeproc-create("/home/pixel/Zotero/styles/american-medical-as..." #f(compiled-function (itemids) #<bytecode -0x7190d3ddff05f13>) #f(compiled-function (loc) #<bytecode -0x18864415d32d6563>) "en")
  (let ((proc (citeproc-create style-file (citeproc-itemgetter-from-bibtex bibtex-file) (citeproc-locale-getter-from-dir (or citeproc-org-locales-dir citeproc-org--fallback-locales-dir)) locale))) (setq citeproc-org--proc-cache (list proc style-file bibtex-file locale)) proc)
  (or result (let ((proc (citeproc-create style-file (citeproc-itemgetter-from-bibtex bibtex-file) (citeproc-locale-getter-from-dir (or citeproc-org-locales-dir citeproc-org--fallback-locales-dir)) locale))) (setq citeproc-org--proc-cache (list proc style-file bibtex-file locale)) proc))
  (let ((style-file (or (citeproc-org--get-option-val "csl_style") citeproc-org-default-style-file citeproc-org--fallback-style-file)) (locale (or (citeproc-org--get-option-val "language") "en")) result) (let ((--dash-source-0-- citeproc-org--proc-cache)) (if --dash-source-0-- (let ((c-proc (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-0-- ...)))) (if c-proc (let ((c-style-file ...)) (if c-style-file (let ... ...))))))) (or result (let ((proc (citeproc-create style-file (citeproc-itemgetter-from-bibtex bibtex-file) (citeproc-locale-getter-from-dir (or citeproc-org-locales-dir citeproc-org--fallback-locales-dir)) locale))) (setq citeproc-org--proc-cache (list proc style-file bibtex-file locale)) proc)))
  citeproc-org--get-cleared-proc("/home/arcotpixel/bib/references.bib")
  (let* ((--dash-source-3-- (citeproc-org--cites-and-notes parsed-buffer mode)) (cite-ents (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- (setq --dash-source-3-- (cdr --dash-source-3--))))) (cites-and-notes (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- (setq --dash-source-3-- (cdr --dash-source-3--))))) (cite-count (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- (setq --dash-source-3-- (cdr --dash-source-3--))))) (footnote-count (car --dash-source-3--)) (--dash-source-4-- (citeproc-org--get-bib-info parsed-buffer mode)) (bib-file (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- (setq --dash-source-4-- (cdr --dash-source-4--))))) (bib-begin (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- (setq --dash-source-4-- (cdr --dash-source-4--))))) (bib-end (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- (setq --dash-source-4-- (cdr --dash-source-4--))))) (print-bib (car --dash-source-4--)) (proc (citeproc-org--get-cleared-proc bib-file)) (cite-info (citeproc-org--assemble-cite-info cites-and-notes cite-count footnote-count (progn (or (progn (and ... t)) (signal 'wrong-type-argument (list ... ...))) (aref (progn (or ... ...) (aref proc 1)) 8)))) (citeproc-org-link-cites (and print-bib citeproc-org-link-cites)) (rendered-cites (citeproc-org--append-and-render-citations cite-info proc backend mode (not (and print-bib citeproc-org-link-cites)))) (rendered-bib (if print-bib (citeproc-org--bibliography proc backend) "")) (offset 0) (bib-inserted nil)) (let* ((--cl-var-- rendered-cites) (rendered nil) (--cl-var-- cite-ents) (cite-ent nil)) (while (and (consp --cl-var--) (progn (setq rendered (car --cl-var--)) (consp --cl-var--))) (setq cite-ent (car --cl-var--)) (let* ((--dash-source-5-- (citeproc-org--element-boundaries cite-ent)) (begin (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-5-- ...))) (end (car --dash-source-5--))) (if (and bib-end (> begin bib-end)) (progn (let* (... ...) (cl--set-buffer-substring v v rendered-bib)) (setq bib-inserted t) (setq offset (+ offset ...)))) (if (and (s-starts-with-p "[fn::" rendered) (= (char-before ...) 32)) (progn (setq begin (- begin 1)))) (let* ((v (+ begin offset)) (v (+ end offset))) (cl--set-buffer-substring v v rendered)) (setq offset (+ offset (- (length rendered) (- end begin))))) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--)) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--))) nil) (if (and bib-end (not bib-inserted)) (progn (let* ((v (+ bib-begin offset)) (v (+ bib-end offset))) (cl--set-buffer-substring v v rendered-bib)))))
  (progn (let* ((--dash-source-3-- (citeproc-org--cites-and-notes parsed-buffer mode)) (cite-ents (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- (setq --dash-source-3-- (cdr --dash-source-3--))))) (cites-and-notes (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- (setq --dash-source-3-- (cdr --dash-source-3--))))) (cite-count (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- (setq --dash-source-3-- (cdr --dash-source-3--))))) (footnote-count (car --dash-source-3--)) (--dash-source-4-- (citeproc-org--get-bib-info parsed-buffer mode)) (bib-file (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- (setq --dash-source-4-- (cdr --dash-source-4--))))) (bib-begin (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- (setq --dash-source-4-- (cdr --dash-source-4--))))) (bib-end (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- (setq --dash-source-4-- (cdr --dash-source-4--))))) (print-bib (car --dash-source-4--)) (proc (citeproc-org--get-cleared-proc bib-file)) (cite-info (citeproc-org--assemble-cite-info cites-and-notes cite-count footnote-count (progn (or (progn ...) (signal ... ...)) (aref (progn ... ...) 8)))) (citeproc-org-link-cites (and print-bib citeproc-org-link-cites)) (rendered-cites (citeproc-org--append-and-render-citations cite-info proc backend mode (not (and print-bib citeproc-org-link-cites)))) (rendered-bib (if print-bib (citeproc-org--bibliography proc backend) "")) (offset 0) (bib-inserted nil)) (let* ((--cl-var-- rendered-cites) (rendered nil) (--cl-var-- cite-ents) (cite-ent nil)) (while (and (consp --cl-var--) (progn (setq rendered (car --cl-var--)) (consp --cl-var--))) (setq cite-ent (car --cl-var--)) (let* ((--dash-source-5-- (citeproc-org--element-boundaries cite-ent)) (begin (car-safe ...)) (end (car --dash-source-5--))) (if (and bib-end (> begin bib-end)) (progn (let* ... ...) (setq bib-inserted t) (setq offset ...))) (if (and (s-starts-with-p "[fn::" rendered) (= ... 32)) (progn (setq begin ...))) (let* ((v ...) (v ...)) (cl--set-buffer-substring v v rendered)) (setq offset (+ offset (- ... ...)))) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--)) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--))) nil) (if (and bib-end (not bib-inserted)) (progn (let* ((v (+ bib-begin offset)) (v (+ bib-end offset))) (cl--set-buffer-substring v v rendered-bib))))))
  (if mode (progn (let* ((--dash-source-3-- (citeproc-org--cites-and-notes parsed-buffer mode)) (cite-ents (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- (setq --dash-source-3-- ...)))) (cites-and-notes (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- (setq --dash-source-3-- ...)))) (cite-count (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- (setq --dash-source-3-- ...)))) (footnote-count (car --dash-source-3--)) (--dash-source-4-- (citeproc-org--get-bib-info parsed-buffer mode)) (bib-file (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- (setq --dash-source-4-- ...)))) (bib-begin (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- (setq --dash-source-4-- ...)))) (bib-end (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- (setq --dash-source-4-- ...)))) (print-bib (car --dash-source-4--)) (proc (citeproc-org--get-cleared-proc bib-file)) (cite-info (citeproc-org--assemble-cite-info cites-and-notes cite-count footnote-count (progn (or ... ...) (aref ... 8)))) (citeproc-org-link-cites (and print-bib citeproc-org-link-cites)) (rendered-cites (citeproc-org--append-and-render-citations cite-info proc backend mode (not (and print-bib citeproc-org-link-cites)))) (rendered-bib (if print-bib (citeproc-org--bibliography proc backend) "")) (offset 0) (bib-inserted nil)) (let* ((--cl-var-- rendered-cites) (rendered nil) (--cl-var-- cite-ents) (cite-ent nil)) (while (and (consp --cl-var--) (progn (setq rendered ...) (consp --cl-var--))) (setq cite-ent (car --cl-var--)) (let* ((--dash-source-5-- ...) (begin ...) (end ...)) (if (and bib-end ...) (progn ... ... ...)) (if (and ... ...) (progn ...)) (let* (... ...) (cl--set-buffer-substring v v rendered)) (setq offset (+ offset ...))) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--)) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--))) nil) (if (and bib-end (not bib-inserted)) (progn (let* ((v ...) (v ...)) (cl--set-buffer-substring v v rendered-bib)))))))
  (let* ((parsed-buffer (org-element-parse-buffer)) (mode (citeproc-org--determine-mode parsed-buffer))) (if mode (progn (let* ((--dash-source-3-- (citeproc-org--cites-and-notes parsed-buffer mode)) (cite-ents (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- ...))) (cites-and-notes (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- ...))) (cite-count (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-3-- ...))) (footnote-count (car --dash-source-3--)) (--dash-source-4-- (citeproc-org--get-bib-info parsed-buffer mode)) (bib-file (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- ...))) (bib-begin (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- ...))) (bib-end (car-safe (prog1 --dash-source-4-- ...))) (print-bib (car --dash-source-4--)) (proc (citeproc-org--get-cleared-proc bib-file)) (cite-info (citeproc-org--assemble-cite-info cites-and-notes cite-count footnote-count (progn ... ...))) (citeproc-org-link-cites (and print-bib citeproc-org-link-cites)) (rendered-cites (citeproc-org--append-and-render-citations cite-info proc backend mode (not ...))) (rendered-bib (if print-bib (citeproc-org--bibliography proc backend) "")) (offset 0) (bib-inserted nil)) (let* ((--cl-var-- rendered-cites) (rendered nil) (--cl-var-- cite-ents) (cite-ent nil)) (while (and (consp --cl-var--) (progn ... ...)) (setq cite-ent (car --cl-var--)) (let* (... ... ...) (if ... ...) (if ... ...) (let* ... ...) (setq offset ...)) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--)) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--))) nil) (if (and bib-end (not bib-inserted)) (progn (let* (... ...) (cl--set-buffer-substring v v rendered-bib))))))))
  (if (memq backend citeproc-org-ignore-backends) (citeproc-org--citelinks-to-legacy) (let* ((parsed-buffer (org-element-parse-buffer)) (mode (citeproc-org--determine-mode parsed-buffer))) (if mode (progn (let* ((--dash-source-3-- (citeproc-org--cites-and-notes parsed-buffer mode)) (cite-ents (car-safe ...)) (cites-and-notes (car-safe ...)) (cite-count (car-safe ...)) (footnote-count (car --dash-source-3--)) (--dash-source-4-- (citeproc-org--get-bib-info parsed-buffer mode)) (bib-file (car-safe ...)) (bib-begin (car-safe ...)) (bib-end (car-safe ...)) (print-bib (car --dash-source-4--)) (proc (citeproc-org--get-cleared-proc bib-file)) (cite-info (citeproc-org--assemble-cite-info cites-and-notes cite-count footnote-count ...)) (citeproc-org-link-cites (and print-bib citeproc-org-link-cites)) (rendered-cites (citeproc-org--append-and-render-citations cite-info proc backend mode ...)) (rendered-bib (if print-bib ... "")) (offset 0) (bib-inserted nil)) (let* ((--cl-var-- rendered-cites) (rendered nil) (--cl-var-- cite-ents) (cite-ent nil)) (while (and ... ...) (setq cite-ent ...) (let* ... ... ... ... ...) (setq --cl-var-- ...) (setq --cl-var-- ...)) nil) (if (and bib-end (not bib-inserted)) (progn (let* ... ...))))))))
  citeproc-org-render-references(html)
  run-hook-with-args(citeproc-org-render-references html)
  org-export-as(html nil nil nil (:output-file "article.html"))
  org-export-to-file(html "article.html" nil nil nil nil nil)
  org-html-export-to-html(nil nil nil nil)
  org-export-dispatch(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil)
  call-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil nil)
  command-execute(org-export-dispatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Emacs seems to have been compiled without libxml2 support, and therefore citeproc is unable to parse the bibliography style.